# Closed form solution

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization

I have the following optimization problem:
$$\min_{\mathbf{G}} \|\mathbf{B(A+G)\|_F^2} \quad{} \\\text{subject to} \quad{} \mathbf{\|C^T(A+G)\|_F^2\leq \gamma \|A^T(A+G)\|_F^2 }  \quad{},
\\ \mathbf{\|I-A^T(A+G)\|_F^2 \leq \alpha}$$

$\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix, $\mathbf{B} \in R^{P\times N}$, $\mathbf{A} \in R^{N\times M} $,  $\mathbf{C} \in R^{N\times K}$ and are all known. $\mathbf{\|\cdot\|_F}$ is the frobenius norm, $\mathbf{(\cdot)^T}$ is the transpose and $\gamma, \alpha$ are constants. $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{C}$ are a subset of the size $N$ identity matrix.

Is there any closed form solution? and if not I would be grateful if you could point me to a solver that can solve this numerically. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not convex for general values of $A,B,C$, due to the first inequality constraint.

Comment: @MichaelGrant $A$ and $C$ are a subset of the size $N$ identity matrix, they are selection matrices. Does that help at all.

Comment: Perhaps. The problem is the presence of a convex quadratic on the right-hand side of the inequality. If you can somehow eliminate all quadratics on the right-hand side *without* just subtracting from both sides and rendering the left-hand side nonconvex, you will be OK. But short of that, no.

Comment: @MichaelGrant if I expanded the second constraint as $\mathbf{M-2trace\{(A+G)^TA\}+trace\{A^T(A+G)(A+G)^T\}\leq \alpha}$ and the first constraint as: $\mathbf{\|C^T(A+G)\|_F^2\leq \gamma (trace\{A^T(A+G)(A+G)^TA\}) }$. Assuming the second constraint is satisfied I can rewrite the first constraint as: $\mathbf{\|C^T(A+G)\|_F^2\leq \gamma (\alpha + 2trace\{(A+G)^TA\} - M) }$. Is this convex now?

Comment: That will not give you the same feasible set. Perform the same logic on, e.g., the following scalar nonconvex disconnected set $\{(x+1)^2 \leq 4x^2, x^2 \leq 100 \} $. You will get an outer approximation of the feasible set as you implicitly use the best possible rhs of the nonconvex inequality

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was a bit too pessimistic in my comment regarding the relaxation. If the second constraint is tight at optimality, the two models are equivalent. Solve the relaxation, and if the original constraints are satisfied, the original problem has been solved. Hence, in some cases, the problem can be solved somewhat easily as it is a convex quadratically constrained program (or more generally, a second-order cone program)

Here is a trial example implemented in the MATLAB Toolbox YALMIP (developed by me). As the data is random, I don't know how relevant the test is, but when the underlying solver (I used gurobi) finds a solution to the relaxation, the solution is correct.

```
p = 5;
n = 4;
m = 3;
k = 2;
alpha = 1;
gamma = 1;

B = randn(p,n);
A = randn(n,m);
C = randn(n,m);
G = sdpvar(n,m,'full');

Objective = norm(B*(A+G),'fro');

C1 = norm(eye(m)-A'*(A+G),'fro')^2 <= alpha;
bound = alpha + 2*trace((A+G)'*A)-m;
C2 = norm(C'*(A+G),'fro')^2 <= gamma*bound;

solvesdp([C1,C2],Objective)
% Display values
alpha - norm(eye(m) - A'*(A+G),'fro')^2
gamma*norm(A'*(A+G),'fro')^2 - norm(C'*(A+G),'fro')^2
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try that out and post the results here.

Comment: I tried the problem with the relaxation in YALMIP with the data I have, the "original" constraints are satisfied, so it looks like the relaxation works. I beieve you meant alpha - norm(eye(m) - A'*(A+G),'fro')^2 in your code above for checking the constraint. Also thank you for YALMIP, it is great.

Comment: For the relaxed problem, is it possible to write $G$ in a closed form, perhaps using Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: Fixed the missing square. No, I don't think there is any simple useful closed form.